# Finding the roots of the polynomial $t^{1000} + t^{100} +1$ in the field with $13$ elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

My attempt so far has been to figure out the $\gcd(t^{1000} +t^{100}+1, t^{13}-t) \pmod{13}$ as shown in class but I am not sure why this method works, so explanation on this would be great.

Next, I reduced to finding the $\gcd(2t^4 +1, t^{13} -t)$ by Fermat's little theorem. Finally, I tried to factor $2t^4+1$ but found it is an irreducible polynomial as it is equal to $2(t^4-6)$. So what can I say about the gcd then?

Comment: Might simplify matters to substitute $z=t^{100}$.   Then you are first looking to solve $z^{10}+z+1=0$.

Comment: I don't see how this is better than using fermat's little theorem

Comment: Note that $t\equiv 0$ is not a solution, Now reduction mod $12$ gers us to $2t^4+1\equiv 0$, Thus if we want to do no further thinking trying $t=1$ ro $6$ will do the job.

Comment: sorry why did you check 1 and 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By FLT, $t^{13}\equiv t\pmod{13}$.  Hence finding the gcd is equivalent to using FLT "as much as possible" to reduce the problem.
2. Once you have $2t^4+1$, just plug in all 13 values to find the roots.

Comment: oh ok! Thank you very much P.S How do you know when you have reduced the complexity of a number theory problem enough to just brute force it?

Comment: The $13$ values can be reduced to $7$ due to parity.